# Rails Twilio callback event listener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twilio

In Twilio, once you send a text message, it fires a few POST requests to the statusCallbackUrl.  How do I listen for this callback in my angular/rails app? I see the posts being made in the console.  I would simply like to just trigger a notification alert( without refreshing the page preferably) once a post request has been made by twilio.  Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would recommend looking into [Server Sent Events (SSE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) and [`ActionController::Live::SSE`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live/SSE.html).

SSE are a way of sending data from a server to your front end. The data is then received in your front end JavaScript and you can update your view that way without reloading the page.

There are some good blog posts that show how to use SSE with Rails, take a look at:

- [Mini Chat with Rails at Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/mini-chat-rails-server-sent-events/)
- [Aaron Paterson's introduction to Live streaming of arbitrary data](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html)
- [An example of connecting Rails SSE with Angular JS](http://dius.com.au/2014/03/21/server-sent-events-rails-4-angularjs/)

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: This is the best lead I've had so far. Going to try these solutions.  Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: No problem Chris. Give me a shout if I can help at all.